# how do interact children object in cube object - three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

i have one main cube object wireFrame:

```
var cubeGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 50, 50, 50 );
```

and some cube not wireFrame :

```
var cubeTemp = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 10, 10, 10 );
```

i want rotate cubeGeometry then cubetemp rotated too, so i add some cubeTemp into cubeGeometry by add method :

```
cubeGeometry.add(cube);
```

Now i only need interact with cubeTemp in cubeGeometry, How can i do? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to access cubeTemp, do:

```
var cubeTemp = cubeGeometry.children[0];
```